# is it possible to call an onload function in location.href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to call an onload function in  location.href like this...(jQuery)

```
 location.href =getContextPath()+"/home/returnSeachResult?search="$('#id-search-text-box').val()"&category="$('#search_concept').text()" onload='javascript: searchProductList('+category+','+searchdata+')'";
```

please help me...thanks in advance

Comment: to put it bluntly ... no

Comment: You can add hash with category and searchdata and on the resulted page read the hash and call a function.

Comment: Question aside, there appears to be a lot of syntax issues in your code. Are you missing the concatenation operator?

Comment: The other option is to load the resulting page using ajax and then call your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
$(function() {  
    searchProductList('+category+','+searchdata+');
    location.href =getContextPath()+"/home/returnSeachResult?search=" + $('#id-search-text-box').val() + "&category=" + $('#search_concept').text(); 
})
```

Comment: this will destroy the result of searchProductList function because of location change.

Comment: may be add callback to `searchProductList `, like `searchProductList('+category+','+searchdata+', function() {     location.href =getContextPath()+"/home/returnSeachResult?search=" + $('#id-search-text-box').val() + "&category=" + $('#search_concept').text(); 
 });`

Comment: It would be the same the result of searchProductList will go away, but this time it will wait until it's finish before load another page.